# Transfer android speaker output to windows pc over wifi

Tags: wi-fi, audio

I Google for it but didn't find any solution: **How to transfer/stream android sound output to pc?**

I want to transfer all sound that android speaker plays, that includes app sound, games sound. I know about different music streaming apps like vlc app. But I want to transfer all sound not just song or video sound.

As I want to use it from a "far end", it must work wirelessly. Cable-bound solutions don't work for this case.

Comment: Might not be what you want to hear, but the easiest way probably is plugging a cable with one end into your Android's 3.5" headphone jack, and the other end to "line in" on your computer's sound card.

Comment: Yeah but I want to use it from far end

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've [edit]ed that into your question directly, so potential answerers do not miss it.